# Is it possible to have multiple methods in my mapper interface, almost the same but with different return object?

Tags: java, mapstruct

Is it possible to have, for example, 2 methods in my mapper interface, almost the same but with a different return object (with smaller amount of fields)? I created an additional DTO object which is smaller than the original object (eg. MySmallDto). Do I have to create a new mapper interface or can I reuse the logic in my existing mapper?

```
public interface SearchDtoMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "lPlace", source = "route", qualifiedByName = "SpotToLPlace")
    @Mapping(target = "uPlace", source = "route", qualifiedByName = "SpotToUPlace")
    MyBigDto map(Route route);
```

In the same mapper I want to have something like:

```
    @Mapping(target = "lPlace", source = "route", qualifiedByName = "SpotToLPlace")
    @Mapping(target = "uPlace", source = "route", qualifiedByName = "SpotToUPlace")
    MySmallDto map(Route route);
```

Comment: MapStruct can generate the two methods, but the Java compiler will consider them to be ambiguous because they have the same name and parameters. But you don't need a new interface, you just need to change the method name.

Comment: The two methods must at least have different names. In Java, a class or interface cannot have two methods with the same name and same number of arguments with the same type, and have only a different return type.

Comment: ok I thought that only name "map" is allowed

Comment: The name of the methods doesn't matter for MapStruct, you can give the methods any name you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapStruct can have as many methods with as many source and return types that you want.

So in your example you can do something like:

```java
public interface SearchDtoMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "lPlace", source = "route", qualifiedByName = "SpotToLPlace")
    @Mapping(target = "uPlace", source = "route", qualifiedByName = "SpotToUPlace")
    MyBigDto map(Route route);

    @Mapping(target = "lPlace", source = "route", qualifiedByName = "SpotToLPlace")
    @Mapping(target = "uPlace", source = "route", qualifiedByName = "SpotToUPlace")
    MySmallDto mapSmall(Route route);
}
```